# Need advices about pushing data from server to client application

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, inter-process-communicat

I have been developing a physical security application which will run on security operators pc.

In server side i have a windows service collecting the alarms from third party systems like smoke sensors, access control in realtime. The server application logs the alarms into SQL database.

I need to push the alarms from server to client applications(security operators GUI) instantly.
The question is :

Could you offer a technique to push the alarms to the client application's GUI instantly.

All the server and client are in .NET framework 3.5 and 4.0

I have been reading articles about named pipes,wcf and really confused.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a [Duplex Service Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) (a ServiceContract with a [CallbackContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx)) in conjunction with a binding that supports such contracts, e.g. [WSDualHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586909.aspx).

Your client would implement the callback interface, which is called by the server whenever alarms are to be published.